# Does not animate on pressing animate button

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Have an animation project which does not animate when I press the button. What am I doing wrong. Here is the code in the view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var startStopAnimating: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    // image arrays
    let frames: [String] = ["frame1.png", "frame2.png", "frame3.png", "frame4.png", "frame5.png", "frame6.png", "frame7.png"]
    let swan: [String] = ["swanFrame1", "swanFrame2", "swanFrame3"]
    let swirl: [String] = ["swirlFrame1", "swirlFrame2", "swirlFrame3"]
    let starryNight: [String] = ["starryNight1", "starryNight2", "starryNight3"]
    let doveWithBranch: [String] = ["doveWithBranch1", "doveWithBranch2", "doveWithBranch3"]
    let tanCandles: [String] = ["tanCandles1", "tanCandles2", "tanCandles3", "tanCandles4"]
    let buddhaFloat: [String] = ["buddhaFloat1", "buddhaFloat2", "buddhaFloat3", "buddhaFloat4", "buddhaFloat5", "buddhaFloat6"]

    // timer vars
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var isAnimating = true
    var counter = 1
    var arrayIndex = 0
    var pauseCheck = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        randomizedFuncs()
    }



    @IBAction func startStopAnimateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if isAnimating == true {
            timer.invalidate()
            startStopAnimating.setTitle("Animate", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            startStopAnimating.setTitle("Stop Animating", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "pauseCheck", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    func framesFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == swan.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 1

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "swanFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    func swanFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == frames.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 2

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "swirlFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    func swirlFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == swirl.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 3

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "starryNightFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    func starryNightFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == starryNight.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 4

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "doveWithBranchFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    func doveWithBranchFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == doveWithBranch.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 5

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "tanCandlesFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    func tanCandlesFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == tanCandles.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 6

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "buddhaFloatFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    func buddhaFloatFunc() {
        if arrayIndex == buddhaFloat.count-1 {
            arrayIndex = 0
        } else {
            arrayIndex++
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: frames[arrayIndex])
        counter++
        pauseCheck = 7

        if counter == 50 {
            arrayIndex = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "frames Func", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isAnimating = true
            counter = 0
            arrayIndex = 0
        }
    }

    // pauses the images and restarts them where they left off, its called in the start/stop action

    func pauseCheckFunc() {

        if pauseCheck == 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "framesFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else if pauseCheck == 2 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "swanFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else if pauseCheck == 3 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "swirlFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else if pauseCheck == 4 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "starryNightFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else if pauseCheck == 5 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "doveWithBranchFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else if pauseCheck == 6 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "tanCandlesFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else if pauseCheck == 7 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "buddhaFloatFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    func randomizedFuncs() {

        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(7)))

        if randomNumber == 0 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "swanFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        } else if randomNumber == 1 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "framesFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        } else if randomNumber == 2 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "swirlFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        } else if randomNumber == 3 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "starryNightFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        } else if randomNumber == 4 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "doveWithBranchFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        } else if randomNumber == 5 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "tanCandlesFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        } else if randomNumber == 6 {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "buddhaFloatFunc", userInfo: "nil", repeats: true)
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `pauseCheck` as a selector but that's not a function in your code. I think you meant `pauseCheckFunc`?

Also I don't see anywhere in your code a command to actually start animating. You also don't properly set animation frames on your UIImages. It's unclear why you're using timers to animate images. You can just set an array of images to the `animationImages` property of your UIImages, and just use `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()` to start and stop animation.